# Is it OK to use wash-in DWR on synthetic fill insulated clothing made with PrimaLoft?

Tags: gear, gear-care, waterproofing, insulation

I have heard mixed opinions on using wash-in DWR (i.e. Nikwax TX.Direct wash in or Gear Aid Wash In Water Repellent or Grangers Wash + Repel) for shells and other garments (some people say that it reduces breathability by filing the pores of the the interior).

I haven't seen much on synthetic fill garments and how using wash-in DWR will affect them. I ask because I'm looking at a used PrimaLoft jacket that was washed with wash-in DWR, and I'm wondering if that's going to significantly negatively impact the breathability and insulation capabilities of the jacket.

Does anyone have any information or thoughts/experience with this?

Comment: Just generally commenting that **Spray on DWR >> Wash in DWR**. Use tech washes, but waterproof with sprays

Comment: Or this [When should I use spray-on versus wash-in waterproofer for treating DWR garments?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/5432/11563)

Comment: Thanks @MartinF The second post was great!

Comment: usually you wear a waterproof layer on top of your puffy if it rains and you're not moving