# Waterproofing Pendleton jacket. Polyester/cotton blend shell

Tags: gear, waterproof-clothing

I want to apply a waterproof spray to my wife’s Pendleton rain jacket.  I was just going to spray with Silicon, but I found out there are other, probably better choices.

DWR.  Durable Water Repellant.  You can wash it in or spray on.  Spray on makes sense since I don’t want to affect the lining.

Most reviewers say wash it first.  In what, and how?  What are the best products specifically for preparing for spray treatment.

The top spray brands are NikWax and Rivivex.  How to choose?  Do you spray wet or dry?

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Or this [When should I use spray-on versus wash-in waterproofer for treating DWR garments?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/5432/11563)

Comment: Nikwax also make a detergent for waterproof gear. That's what I use before their wash in proofer.

Comment: Does your wife want you to do anything to her Pendleton jacket? That is question number one...