# Disposal of Gore-Tex or other membrane products

Tags: clothing, gore-tex

Somebody told me that Gore-Tex products would be hazardous waste. Is this true? If I want to dispose of them, what should I do? What are the dangerous substances?

Is this true for other breathable membranes as well? Are there membranes that are free from toxic substances?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Goretex, generally consists of three chemicals.

### The outer

The outer (wear resistant part) is simply nylon or polyester.

This is typically non-hazardous and can be disposed as any other plastic (bearing in mind the long periods of time this is likely going to take to decompose)

### The inner

This is the "Gore-tex layer". Goretex itself is simply a [Polyurethane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyurethane)/[PTFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytetrafluoroethylene) polymer based plastic. [Fully reacted (as in Goretex) polyurethane polymer is chemically inert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyurethane#Health_and_safety). [PTFE does generate potentially noxious gases at temperatures over 250C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytetrafluoroethylene#Safety), So don't burn it! Again this is typically deemed safe though (as above) it takes a long time to decompose.

The [production of PTFE also involves](http://www.theguardian.com/environment/2009/oct/11/outdoor-clothing-ethical-living) the chemical [PFOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfluorooctanoic_acid) . [This is highly toxic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfluorooctanoic_acid#Health_concerns). Though all of this chemical is removed by the final product (i.e. *the Goretex itself is not toxic*) this chemical (used in the **production** of Goretex/PTFE) is potentially long lived in the environment. Several [legal actions have been successful against DuPont](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfluorooctanoic_acid#Legal_actions) (though no liabillity was admitted) against the release of this chemical into water course.

### DWR

Goretex is also coated with [Durable water repellent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durable_Water_Repellent) coating. This is a [Fluoropolymer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/5115/2766). Again this is typically safe. If large amounts of Fluoropolymer's get into water they can cause issues with fish, aquatic animals, etc. So again this is an environmentally sensitive product.

---

### To summarise

- Goretex is *safe* for humans, all the chemicals involved are generally inert and have been passed as safe by every government agency in the world
- When Goretex is disposed of it can cause environmental damage
- The production of the chemicals in Goretex are themselves
  environmentally sensitive, the production creates pollution and uses
  oil as the main ingredient.

---

> Is this true for other breathable membranes as well?

Typically **yes**, they all use variations on the theme above

> Are there membranes that are free from toxic substances?

**Yes** plenty! Wool, wax jackets, etc. *Are they as effective and breathable*, typically **no**, especially when your talking about breathabillity.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.gore-tex.com.au/faq/w1/i1085252/

> How should I dispose of a GORE-TEX® product in an environmentally safe
>   way? Garments or footwear made from Gore laminates can be safely
>   disposed of just like any other apparel product.
>
> Contrary to most other plastics, Polytetrafluoroethylene (PTFE) – the
>   raw material of our membrane - is not made or processed using
>   plasticizers or stabilizers. It doesn’t contain residuals like heavy
>   metals, organotin compounds or phthalates. If disposed of in a
>   landfill, PTFE will not degrade, so it will not contribute to the
>   formation of greenhouse gases (i.e. Methane) or release substances
>   into the water or air. In an incineration plant, PTFE is safely
>   converted to CO2 and Fluorspar. Potentially harmful gases are captured
>   by pollution control devices (alkaline scrubbers) that have been in
>   place for a number of decades.
>
> Finding ways to extend the useful life of a product has always been
>   the environmentally preferred option over product disposal. One might
>   wish to consider donating footwear or garments to charities or
>   repurposing the product for other applications.

The Gore Tex answer to this seems very straightforward and reasonable to me.

Comment: Not criticising the answer, but; I'm not sure stating that *PTFE will not degrade* makes it environmentally sound. So, it'll just be around forever. I also think the claims (by Gore) *that harmful gases are captured by pollution control devices* is more than a little bit glib. So China (for example) have these? Doubtful and these scrubbers remove all the CO2 (again I doubt it). As far as I know the only way to successfully remove all CO2 from burning is [carbon capture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_capture_and_storage). This technology is in it's infancy and is not widely used.

Comment: @Liam -- CO2 is not generally considered a "harmful gas".  People exhale it all the time.  The amounts of CO2 emitted by destroying goretex are hardly going to be significant enough to influence climate on the scale that is generally of concern.  Too much of *anything* is bad.  To say that because goretex emits some gas when burned does not substantially differentiate goretex from any other material known to man, natural or otherwise.

Comment: [CO2, 100% is a greenhouse gas.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenhouse_gas#Greenhouse_gases) People do exhale it, but burning hydrocarbons (such as PTFE) produces large amounts of CO2 when compared to natural products (it's basically made form Carbon which oxidises when burnt). I'm not saying it's going to single handedly bring down the planet, but neither is it (as Gore are trying to say) environmentally inert. It's as [polluting as any other plastic based product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_pollution).

Comment: You know what re-reading it, they've worded it very cleverly. They initially talk about *environmentally safe way*. They then state that *PTFE is safely converted to CO2 and Fluorspar*. Which is true but fails to point out that these gases are environmentally sensitive. They then state *Potentially harmful gases are captured by pollution control devices*. But it it doesn't make the link between CO2 and the scrubbers. The Scrubbers will not remove CO2. They are designed to remove things like ammonia or hydrochloric acid

Comment: @Liam -- If you are claiming that Goretex produces enough C02 to matter, please document it.  

All trash potential produces C02 when burned.  You have done nothing to identify this as "hazardous waste".  "Causes pollution via C02" does not equal "hazardous waste".  Otherwise every life form on the planet would be "hazardous waste" by your claim.

The question was not "Is GoreTex inert".   Although there again, please point me to something that is by your definition.  Even food produces C02 and is thereby "hazardous waste" by your definition.

Comment: Calling anything that produces C02 "hazardous waste" is plainly absurd.

Comment: Ok, my comment was I'm not *"Not criticising the answer, but"*. I was simply pointing out that the Gore version of what is *"environmentally safe"* and many other peoples differ. I also did not state that *"CO2 is hazardous waste"*, I said *"CO2 is a greenhouse gas"*.